# Unable to select header/menu dropdown items using xpath/css traversing

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have attached the sample UI image of Application under test. 
I am using webdriver with java to get the list of header values & also get the drop down values.

### MY QUESTIONS -

1) using xpath, i am not able to get the size & also the text values of ONLY header (Test1, Test2, test3, help)

2) Secondly Test1 has drop down values, similarly Test2 & Test3.
i should be able to get the size of test1 (should be 4), and then get the text values (Get Class 1 etc..) based on XPATH location.

CODE

```
Grid.driver().get("https://testpt1qa.com");

// Get Size of the Navigation Header
WebElement parent = Grid.driver().findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='main-menu']"));
List<WebElement> child = parent.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

/**
 * THIS IS listing all the links under Test1,Test2,Test3 & Help
 */
System.out.println(child.size());

for (WebElement webElement : child) { 
    String sizeval = webElement.getSize().toString();
    System.out.println("**********  " + sizeval);
....
....
```

sample HTML Code

```
<nav id="main-menu" role="navigation" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <ul style="background-color: transparent;">
        <li style="background-color: transparent;">
            <a id="header-test1" class="selected" aria-controls="submenu-test1" rel="menuitem" href="https://testpt1qa.com" role="button" aria-expanded="true" style="background-color: transparent;">Test1</a>
            <div id="submenu-test1" class="menu-wrapper on open done" aria-labelledby="header-test1" role="region" tabindex="-1">
                <ul id="header-test1-menu" class="subnav list " style="background-color: transparent;">
                    <li style="background-color: transparent;">
                        <a href="https://testpt1qa.com/kp/helper5" style="background-color: transparent;">Get Class 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://testpt1qa.com/kp/helper1" style="background-color: transparent;">Get Class 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://testpt1qa.com/kp/helper2">Get Class 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://testpt1qa.com/kp/helper3">Get Class 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                </ul>
.....
.....
```

Based on the above code, it prints the size of all dropdown values and header values, instead of specific ones.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle to see your page live

Comment: My page works only within the corp network, sorry for that, but i have attached a sample html snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `parent.findElements(By.tagName("li"));` returns all `li` elements under `<nav id="main-menu"...`. The code below is a bit verbose, hope this helps.

```
Grid.driver().get("https://testpt1qa.com");

// Get top level parent for all nav elements
WebElement parent = Grid.driver().findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='main-menu']//ul//li"));

// Get the main menu items: main-menu > ul > li > a
// At this point you should have Test1, Test2, Test3 and Help.
List<WebElement> menuItems = parent.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[@rel='menuitem'"));

// Get menu items size
System.out.println("Number of menu items " + menuItems.size());

// Get the text for each menu
for (WebElement menuItem : menuItems) {
    System.out.println(menuItem.getText());

    // Now search for sub menu item by traversing up to the parent of the current menu item
    // This should get you Get Class1 etc based on the current menu in the loop
    List<WebElement> subMenuItems = menuItem.findElements(By.xpath(".//..//div//ul//li//a"));
    System.out.println("Number of sub menu items " + subMenuItems.size());
    for (WebElement subMenuItem : subMenuItems) {
        System.out.println(subMenuItem.getText());
    }
}
```